# Expected unqualified-id before 'xor' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Why the g++ compiler says: error: expected unqualified-id before 'xor' token

```
class BigInteger{
public:
    unsigned *array;

    BigInteger xor(BigInteger bi){    // g++ indicates error this line
        BigInteger n;
        if(bi.array == (unsigned*)0){
            return n;
        }
        return n;
    }
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce that error. And there's no `^` anywhere near the place you indicated.

Comment: @jww: So why didn't you add that to the tags list?

Comment: @jww: You took `g++` out of the title, leaving a comment that tags shouldn't be repeated in titles.  But `g++` is not in the tags.

Comment: @ben - you're right, my bad. I'm out of votes, so all I can do at the moment is menial work like police titles from the home page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`xor` is an *alternative token* for `^` in C++, you can't use it as an identifier. Same for `or`/`bitor` and `and`/`bitand` (`||`, `|`, `&&` and `&` respectively), and a few others. They are essentially keywords like `if` or `for`.

Choose a different name for your function.

Full list of alternative tokens (C++ standard §2.12 *Keywords*, see §2.6 *Alternative tokens* for the mappings):

- and
- and_eq
- bitand
- bitor
- compl
- not
- not_eq
- or
- or_eq
- xor
- xor_eq

Comment: And yes, this sucks.  Goes against the language design principles of keeping the language itself, and particularly the keyword count, short and sweet and doing as much as possible with libraries.  But it made it into the Standard.

Comment: On the bright side, it means you can write it as `operator xor`.

Comment: @Ben: indeed. Not exactly sure if that's what the OP is going for though.

Answer (score 0):

Groan.  Yes, this very thing is one of those chase-your-tail and then realize "What?" and shake your head situations.

In my case similar, I have a class definition, which defines a class method:

```
List* xor(List* list)
```

And one gets the g++ useful error message of:
*error: expected unqualified-id before ‘^’ token*

Eventually one finds that xor is a synonym for ^ and as such cannot be a function name.

What makes it worse (in my case) is that this works perfectly FINE in MS Windows under Visual Studio (2010 in my case).  And is code that has been under development through various Visual Studio versions since 1999 (Visual Studio 6).

So now I need to rename the function and rebuild on Windows as well as g++ on linux... one of those problems that gets bigger as you work on it.